# If I cancel an evolution, can I evolve the same Pokemon later?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

If I cancel an evolution, can I evolve the same Pokemon later ?

I cancelled (for tests) an evolution from [Krokorok](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Krokorok_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) and now I don't know if I should capture another to get the evolution, or if there is any way to evolve him.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you cancel an evolution for a pokemon that evolves when it levels up (I don't know if you can do it otherwise) then if it gains another level it will try to evolve again, so you don't need to capture another one just to get the evolved form.

Comment: As an extreme edge case, note that I do believe you're out of luck if you have a level 100 unevolved pokemon that evolves from leveling.

Comment: @BenBrocka That's true, though I said "if it gains another level..." and that will just never happen.

Comment: Wasn't saying you were wrong, it's just an extra thing to note

Comment: @BenBrocka So in that case. (lv 100) there is no other way, right ?

Comment: @MichelAyres I am pretty certain that is the case.

Comment: @MichelAyres It should also be noted this applies for all generations, no just fifth generation.

Comment: This is pretty old of course, but the comment stream above about level 100 is no longer true of later generations - specifically gen 8 - see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362566/can-a-level-100-pok%c3%a9mon-evolve-in-any-pok%c3%a9mon-series-game