# Can you evolve a Pancham after level 32 in sword?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I know that it needs to have another dark Pokémon in the party to evolve but I did not realize until it was level 33. So is it possible to evolve it at this point or do I have to get another one and level it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pancham will evolve into Pangoro starting at level 32, but will try to evolve every time you level it up (with a Dark type in your party). So it is not necessary to do it at 32, but it can also evolve from leveling from 33 to 34. So you do not need to get another one.

Comment: Note that this applies to all evolutions with a level requirement, not just Pancham. You get another opportunity every time it levels up after that (assuming it meets the other requirements, if any) and as of Gen 8 it can still evolve [even at level 100](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362566/can-a-level-100-pok%c3%a9mon-evolve-in-any-pok%c3%a9mon-series-game).